# Java -- accessing the values by keys and maintaining the order of key-value pairs

Tags: java, linkedhashmap, linkedhashset

I will be processing on a sequence of key-value pairs, and returning them as a `Set`, or rather, a `LinkedHashSet`. 
I'll be merging the elements with the same keys, and process on the values as I go along. 
The output I produce will preserve the sequence of keys in the input.

I can think of 2 alternatives:

1.) Do it all on a `LinkedHashMap`, and convert the result to a `LinkedHasSet`-- load the `LinkedHashMap` to a collection and create a `LinkedHashSet` out of that collection.

2.) Use a `HashMap` and a `LinkedHashSet`. 
`HashMap` is for processing-- to fast-access and update the values, 
and `LinkedHashSet` for maintaining the sequence of keys and ensuring the uniqueness of the keys as i go along. 
In the end, read the final values from the `HashMap` and create another `LinkedHashSet`, this time for key-value pairs and not just keys, and deliver it.

(1) seems much favourable to (2) to me.

Ideally, I'd look to be able to do it all on a `LinkedHashSet`-- 
keep the key-value pairs on a `LinkedHashSet`, but be able to process its elements by keys only-- 
to be able to

i.) access the value pairs, and 
ii.) maintain the uniqueness of the keys

on the keys and not by key-value pairs. But `LinkedHashSet` doesn't have that, and there's no other structure 
in the APIs to do that.

Am I missing something here?

Are there other option(s)?

Thanks in advance.

Not that sharp on the APIs-- wanna make sure.

Comment: why don't you process the same map and return the values or entrySet of the same map.

Comment: I'm not sure what the goal you have in mind here is but it sounds like premature optimization. Unless your data set is ridiculously huge or the processing you are doing is ridiculously slow it doesn't matter. Pick the option that's the simplest to program so you don't tear your hair out when you end up with an error.

Comment: Have a look at the entrySet() method of  java.util.HashMap class. it's a set view of a Map.

Comment: @SantoshJoshi will look to decipher it. not sure yet -- seems promising. thx.